Security implications of exposing server paths in meta tags for JavaScript module configuration
I'm working on a project where we need to create a header that will work across multiple sites within our organization. Currently, the implementation is to include a series of meta tags in the HTML of each site, acting as a config, and then use a JavaScript file to access each of those meta tags individually.
My proposed optimization is to consolidate the configuration into a single JavaScript module (e.g., config-1.js) that exports a JSON object containing the necessary links and paths. This module would be one of many, each site having a different config.js file. This module is then imported into the main header.js file, which each site would also include in a script tag.
My question is: Does exposing the server path of the configuration module in the meta tag introduce any security vulnerabilities? I'm concerned that publishing the location of a file on the server could be a potential issue, even if the file only contains configuration data.
Are there any best practices or alternative approaches to handling this type of configuration securely across multiple sites?
The following is an example of the proposed implementation:
Here's an example of the JSON configuration file (config-1.js):
const config = {
  "Image": "https://example.com/image.png",
  "About": {
    "Our Library": "https://linktoourlibrary.com/ourlibrary",
    "Our Library2": "https://linktoour2library.com/ourlibrary2",
    // ...
  },
  "How to": {
    "Activate your researcher account": "https://linktoourlibrary.com/howto",
    "Request materials": "https://linktoourlibrary.com/request",
    // ...
  },
  "login": "https://website.com/login"
};

export default json;

In the HTML file, we would reference the path to the configuration module using a meta tag:
<meta name="config1-path" content="./config-1.js" />

And in the header.js file, we would import the configuration module using the path specified in the meta tag:
const modulePath = document.querySelector('meta[name="config1-path"]').getAttribute('content');
import(modulePath)
  .then(module => {
    const config = module.default;
    generateNav(config);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("Error with config", error);
  });


I don't see an issue. You're exposing those paths for all of the data, scripts, images, etc. your site uses.

Which of that data do you think is sensitive and needs protection or is otherwise non-public?

I think the issue would be exposing the file path. I am very new to web development, but I'm not sure if it would introduce the possibility of an attacker changing where that content points to/what gets loaded. The two script tags would be in the same domain.

You always have to assume that an attacker can make any arbitrary request to your server. If you don't want them to get particular data, your server must not send it, you cannot rely on the URL (path) being unknown to them or somehow hidden.

But no, the attacker won't be (shouldn't be) able to change the contents of the JS module, just like they can't change the contents your meta tags.
